# Web test details are not displayed when ran from an ordered test

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, webtest, ordered-test

I have an ordered test that contains 4 web tests. The problem is that Visual Studio seems to have a problem loading the test results for an individual test.

I included a screenshot to supplement for the 1000 words. :)

[image: Test results screenshot]

As you may see the 3rd test, called intuitively Webservice03, failed. The screenshot above was taken after I double-clicked on the corresponding line to open the detailed information about that test run. The panels with requests and other useful information are empty.

The issue is quite annoying, because the test is part of a bigger test suite that runs periodically, so when it fails, I have to manually disable the setup and cleanup scripts from the test configuration, run them manually, then run each of the tests manually, instead of just comfortably opening the test results.

Did anyone experienced this problem? 
Thanks.

Version details:

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate
Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel

Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.0.30319 SP1Rel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and tryed to clarify it via Microsoft forum:

[Web test details are not displayed when ran from an ordered test](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstswebtest/thread/44c6ca51-0773-4bfa-8c4e-519b1ee48a2f)

According to the answer you can not have detailed test result for a web test run as a part of an ordered test.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative to Ordered Tests:

1. Add the web tests to a load test
2. In the test mix choose 'Test mix based on sequential test order'.  This will achieve the same thing as an Ordered Test.

   [image]
3. In the load test run settings, make sure 'Save Log on Test Failure' is set to True:

   [image]
4. Set a Constant Load Pattern of 1 user

At the end of the "load" test you will be able to see the number of failures and on the Tables view you can click on the error count which takes you to a dialog that lets you browse the individual web test failures.

[image]

[image]