# VS 2012 Web test details are not displayed when ran from an ordered test

Tags: visual-studio-2012, add-in, performance-testing

Similar question (for VS 2010) like:
[Web test details are not displayed when ran from an ordered test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10554027/web-test-details-are-not-displayed-when-ran-from-an-ordered-test)

After running single web performance test, the detailed results can be viewed, but when put to ordered test, the detailed result is empty.

My installed Visual Studio 2012 version:
Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012
Version 11.0.60315.01 Update 2

Does MS support viewing test results in ordered web performance test in VS 2012?

Or do I need to change some configuration to make it work? Please help. Thank you.

I am new on it. If no such feature in VS 2012, how can I make a add-in? Any resources can help on it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the use of Ordered Tests is discouraged by Microsoft because they have limitations such as this one that you have found.

However there is a solution:

1. Add the web tests to a load test
2. In the test mix choose 'Test mix based on sequential test order'.  This will achieve the same thing as an Ordered Test.

   [image]
3. In the load test run settings:

   - set 'Save Log Frequency for Completed Tests' to 1
   - set 'Timing Details Storage' to 'All Individual Details'
   - (you must have a load test results database set up for this to work)

   [image]
4. Set a Constant Load Pattern of 1 user

At the end of the "load" test you will be able to see all of the individual web test results by selecting the 'Details' view and then mouse-over the line on the user activity graph.  There will appear a tooltip on which you can click a link that opens the individual web test log.  Apologies for the generic image below - it shows a result of multiple virtual users.  But you get the point.
    [image]

For more information see also [Analyzing Load Test Virtual User Activity in the Details View of the Load Test Analyzer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff183349.aspx)